# Create Map in Scala using loop

Tags: scala, for-loop, dictionary, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a map after getting result for each items in the list. Here is what I tried so far:

```
val sourceList: List[(Int, Int)] = ....
val resultMap: Map[Int, Int] = for(srcItem <- sourceList) {
  val result: Int = someFunction(srcItem._1)
  Map(srcItem._1 -> result)
}
```

But I am getting type mismatch error in `IntelliJ` and I am definitely not writing proper syntax here. I don't think I can use `yield` as I don't want List of Map. What is correct way to create Map using for loop. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to create the map out of a list of tuples:

```
val resultMap = sourceList.map(item => (item._1, someFunction(item._1))).toMap
```

Or, in the monadic way:

```
val listOfTuples = for {
  (value, _) <- sourceList
} yield (value, someFunction(value))

val resultMap = listOfTuples.toMap
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid the creation of `listOfTuples` you can make the transformation a lazy one by calling `.view` on `sourceList` and then call `toMap`:

```
val resultMap = sourceList.view
                          .map(item => (item._1, someFunction(item._1)))
                          .toMap
```

Finally, if you really want to avoid generating extra objects you can use a [mutable Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map) instead and append the keys and values to it using `+=` or `.put`